# Finding different combinations of a numeric string that corresponds to letters

Tags: python, string, algorithm, string-matching

Imagine I have an input:

```
['145689']
```

and I have a dictionary `{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3':'c' ..., '26': 'z', '27':' '}`. I am trying to find the different valid combinations of this input string from left to right that can result in all possible strings of characters.

Example input:

```
['11']
```

Example output:

```
['aa', 'j']
```

`'ab'` comes from the combination `'1' '1'` and `'10'` corresponds to `'j'`.

What would be the brute force method to do this?

Comment: You should consider a dictionary with actual numbers instead of strings. If these numbers are exactly the letter position in the dictionary your code can be quite simpler. You just have to find the largest match and then go back for smaller matches.

Comment: Can you give an example that's more than 2 characters? If there are 3 characters does [a], [ab], [abc], and [bc] all count, or not [bc]?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realize that I don't understand you're exmaple output; how does b map to 0, doesn't b map to 2?

Comment: @en_Knight sorry i had a bug in my description. you're right. there's no 0 in the mapping.

Comment: @newenthusiast still doesn't make sense to me - "10 corresponds to 'j'", do you mean "11 corresponds to k", else where do we get the "0" for "10" from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a homework, so here is a reasonable hint.

You take your string `145689`, check for substrings of length maximum 2 (the biggest number is 26) `1`, `14`. If any of them are in the dictionary you run a recursive call to the rest of substring. In my example it will be `call('45689', dict['1'])` and `call('5689', dict['14'])`.

So basically all you need to write is a simple recursive program.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of solving this using recursion(which is a building up process). However, I am not quite sure if the base case would be a string of length 1, or both length 1 and 2?

Comment: @newenthusiast I think you're going to need base cases for 0-length and 1-length, then recursive cases for the 1-length and 2-length substrings.

Comment: @newenthusiast your numbers are from `1` to `27` which means that they can take substrings of length 1 or 2. Your base case will be an empty string. So if you reached an empty string you successfully was able to transform your string.

Comment: For bonus points: during the computation for `'145689'`, you are going to recurse on `'45689'` and `'5689'`; but the recursive call for `'45689'` is *also* going to recurse on `'5689'`. There is a standard trick to compute the result for `'5689'` only once instead of twice and convert this from an exponential algorithm to a linear one -- can you reinvent this trick yourself?

Comment: @DanielWagner not sure whether it is a question for me or for OP, and whether it is actually a question or a friendly hint. But yes, it is called dynamic programming and you can just store computations for some elements that you already computed previously. If something you need to compute was already computed, then ignore it.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Indeed, I'm confident you knew this -- it was mostly a friendly nudge to OP in case they were curious and wanted to learn about a fun corner of CS.